# Select Records From File by Date

Tags: shell, date, awk

I have a file format like:-

```
10077083725 06-OCT-17   32 06-OCT-17
10077083725 09-OCT-17   35 09-OCT-17
```

I want to select records (around 1 million) based on the date conditions in column 4, as in within the last 2 months. 2 solutions:-

1) Convert the format of the date to something like:- `20170610`, and then do simple string comparison using awk.

2) Directly do date comparisons.

Can you suggest which one is better. Also, I was unable to find a solution for the second using shell scripts, so any tips there would be useful.

Comment: the question is unclear, elaborate it. What should be the result of comparison? which columns should be compared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk** solution on MacOSX with *coreutils* installed. To use this on linux, change `gdate` to `date`. My answer is a sort of a combination of both your solutions:

```
# cat tst.awk
BEGIN{d=conv(d)}
d <= conv($4)
func conv(str) {
   cmd = "gdate -d '" str "' +'%Y%m%d'"
   res = ((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "")
   close(cmd)
   return res
}
```

Use as input:

```
# cat file
10077083725 06-OCT-17   32 06-OCT-17
10077083725 09-OCT-17   35 09-OCT-17
```

then:

```
# awk -v d="-9 days" -f tst.awk  file
10077083725 09-OCT-17   35 09-OCT-17
```

Comment: is there any issue using this on terminal (mac).

Comment: MacOSX uses the BSD version of date. You would have to install `coreutils` to get your hands on GNU date. `brew install coreutils` will do here. Next, you would have to change the `date` call to `gdate`. I'm going to adapt my answer reflecting this.